# What series of science fiction books involve the asteroids actually housing entire cultures?

Tags: story-identification

A book I read involved one human being supposedly the first to communicate with a "god", which was actually a huge (in numbers) civilization within an asteroid.

Many asteroids in the Solar system were actually inhabited or alive, and, from time to time would sacrifice one or more of themselves to quiet the noisy upstart civilizations on Earth.

The book I read also involved abductees from different periods in history being transported to another planet, and all arriving about the same time, so humans, reptilians, and grays all arrived around the same time.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like it could be the "Engines of Light" trilogy by author Ken MacLeod, consisting of *Cosmonaut Keep*, *Dark Light*, and *Engine City*.

[This review](http://strangehorizons.com/non-fiction/reviews/engines-of-light-the-gnostic-potboilers-of-ken-macleod/) of the third book gives an example of humanity's contact with a race they call "the gods" who are bacteria colonizing asteroids:

> Engines of Light began in 2000 with Cosmonaut Keep and continued the following year with Dark Light. The series tells the millennia-spanning tale of humankind's contact with a race of "extremophile nanobacteria" -- which the Earthlings call simply "the gods" -- that exist in asteroids and cometary masses throughout the galaxy, linked into a vast cosmic mind of "exquisite sensitivity." The story centers on a group of 21st century cosmonauts propelled by the gods to the planet Mingulay in a region of space 100,000 light years away from Earth. There the cosmonauts find a "Second Sphere" inhabited by deracinated human populations, their planets linked by starfaring giant squid called the kraken and humanoid dinosaurs called the saurs.

[Another review](https://www.tor.com/2010/01/13/unravelling-the-universe-ken-macleods-lemgcosmonaut-keeplemg/) gives the information that the saurs came from Earth and connect to the other part of your memory quite well:

> Many writers would have written an interesting story about Matt and his comrades being suddenly plunged into the complex world of saurs and krakens and Nova Babylonians and Scoffer humans from Croatan. The krakens and the saurs both evolved on Earth and they’ve been bringing peopleand proto people, there are gigants and pithkies which I take to be the two kinds of austrolopithecusfrom Earth to the Second Sphere ever since. The spaceships move instantly at light speed, so it takes no more than a few hours to travel between stars, but years will have passed both on the world you left and the one you’re arriving at. They’re alien tech, and the human merchants who travel on them are passengers.The saurs go around in gravity skiffs, which are flying saucers, and they look like those grey aliens from Roswellbut the saurs in the Second Sphere say they have no information about what any saurs in the solar system may have been doing.

The Nova Babylonians are humans from an earlier time period who were brought to the planet before the main characters were.

Comment: Has to be. @George, do you recall the description of the aliens at all, or of the exploratory mission to investigate them?